# assign Json value to a variable using $.each()

Tags: json, each

I am trying to pass the result of this query as a Json string to Jquery so that I can assign the value to a JQuery variable. Actually there will be more than one key:value pair but I am illustrating my problem with a single pair for simplicity. I am able to console.log the index and value however when I try to assign the value to a variable I get an "undefined" message. I have done this successfully elsewhere and am not sure what i am missing here:

```
$query = (
"SELECT MedCondPrimary, Count(MedCondPrimary) as Count 
FROM Comments 
WHERE MedCondPrimary='Arthritis'");

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

WHILE($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$medcond = $rows['MedCondPrimary'];
$array3[$medcond] = $rows['Count'];
};

$json_count=json_encode($array3);
    echo $json_count; // {"Arthritis":"26"}
```

JQ:
    var tally = ;
    console.log(tally);// Object { Arthritis="26"} should be a string?

```
$.each(tally, function(index, value) {
  console.log(index+":"+value);     //Arthritis:26
  var arthritis = value.Arthritis;
  console.log(arthritis);          //undefined
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code should be using `each()` instead of `$.each()` here.

```
$( tally ).each(function( index, obj ) {
  console.log( index + ":" + obj.Arthritis); // Arthritis:26
  var arthritis = obj.Arthritis;
  console.log( arthritis ); // 26
});
```

`each()` passes the object while `$.each()` passes property-value pairs for an object. You're `$.each()` at the other place must be working because you passed it an array as shown below:

```
// iterating an array
$.each( [{Arthritis:26}], function( index, obj) {
    console.log( obj.Arthritis ); // 26
});
```

***PHP Edit** :*

```
$json_count=json_encode($array3);
echo "[" . $json_count . "]";
```

Comment: So part 2 to my question is: "what do I need to change in my php code in order to use the $each() method".